# How to merge two csv files as worksheets in Excel file using perl

Tags: excel, perl, unix

All,

I have 2 .csv files which has some data in it (test1.csv, test2.csv)

I have to create a new Excel (test.xls) with 2 worksheets test1 and test2

test1 is nothing but contents of test1.csv and test2 is nothing but test2.csv

I am using the below code. but it only creates only empty worksheets.

Can you please let me know how do i load these csv files into worksheets of xls file.

```
#!/opt/perl-5.8.0/bin/perl

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("Test.xls");

$workbook->addworksheet("test1.csv");
$workbook->addworksheet("test2.csv");
$workbook->close();

exit;
```

Comment: See the example here https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/examples/csv2xls.pl to learn how to import the data from csv. You just put the code into function and run it once for each worksheet/file.

Comment: @buff: Nice, but this one parse CSV wrong.

Comment: FIrst merge 2 csv files into single csv file, then add the same in addworksheet

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Can you please be more specific about what's wrong?

Comment: @buff: You should not read io handler line by line directly because then you can cut field with a new line. Recommended way is https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#Reading-a-CSV-file-line-by-line

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: Thanks, good to know! So if Mahesh uses the example and replaces CSV parsing with the recommended way you referenced, he's done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your CSV to XLS format before writing to the workbook.

You could install `Text::CSV_XS` and use the `csv2xls` utility that comes with it.